# How to inherit protected functions from an Actor class?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a class foo which extends actor

```
class foo extends Actor{
  def receive:PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = ???

  protected def fooFunctionIWant = { print("hello")}
}
```

And I have another class "bar" which I want to extend foo so it will inherit the fooFunctionIWant

But when I try:

```
object bar extends foo {
  def barFunc = {
     fooFunctionIWant
  }

}
```

and then:

```
bar.barFunc
```

I get :

```
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [...] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:173) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.$init$(Actor.scala:436) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
```

Comment: Are you creating an actor with `new` or `actorOf`?

Comment: What I do is I call   (new bar).barFunc then I get the error. Sorry I will edit my question..

Comment: you shouldn't create Actors with `new`, that's why you are getting this error

Comment: if bar is an object and not class I still get the same error.. I don't create any new references, i just want to inherit the functions from the actor, is it possible?

Comment: yes it's the same problem. The only correct way to instantiate an `Actor` derived class is to use one of the special methods like `actorOf`.

Comment: So there is no way to inherit from an actor this way? I have to create actor reference and talk through messages with him? Cause I know an actor can extend another actor... but I understand it is different then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only correct way to create an actor instance is by using one of the `actorOf` methods. Using `new Actor` or `object Actor` will fail during runtime.

You can't call any methods within the actor directly, you can only send messages to it and receive messages from it. Otherwise, if that would be possible it would break Actor encapsulation.

If you want to share code between an actor and a regular class you can put that shared code in a trait and inherit from it. However, your actor will be able to use that code internally only and will not expose any methods, its instance type returned from `actorOf` will still be `Actor` only.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)